# Way to use AngularJS in a magazine reader app

Tags: architecture, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I'm learning AngularJS to make an app like [this one](http://autocar.realviewdigital.com/#folio=1).

The example site uses a global JS object for one issue of a magazine to manage pages of it, and uses click handlers to deal w/ page switching and other operations. Also, the in-page effects are triggered by directly invoking JS code.

When implementing this in AngularJS, However, I'm confused about how the architecture could be...
Currently I've only one `IssueDetailController` to respond to `'/:issueId/:pageNumber'`: inside the controller the page content is injected to DOM like `$compile(page_content)(new_scope_for_page_content)`. I'm feeling it's not the correct way.

So my question is, what is a sensible architecture, including:

- structures of controllers/views (Do I need two separated controllers for pages and issues. for example)
- page transition (I've no idea at which point `ng-animate` or a custom directive (wrapping [this jQuery plugin](http://www.builtbywill.com/code/booklet/) for example) could be applied, because the whole controller/view thing is still obscured to me. )

, for a app like the example one, in general? Appreciate your hints =)